# how do you insert associative array to an oracle table in php

Tags: php

I have this array called `lines`. When I do `var_dump($lines)`, I get this result back:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(21) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "49992904"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "283699"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "9"
    [6]=>
    string(3) "610"
    [7]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [8]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [9]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [10]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [11]=>
    string(4) "1142"
    [12]=>
    string(5) "61219"
    [13]=>
    string(5) "21873"
    [14]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [15]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [16]=>
    string(2) "91"
    [17]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [18]=>
    string(4) "1.90"
    [19]=>
    string(4) "11.9"
    [20]=>
    string(8) "15:03:46"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(21) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "49986779"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "291340"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "11"
    [6]=>
    string(3) "667"
    [7]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [8]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [9]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [10]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [11]=>
    string(4) "1286"
    [12]=>
    string(5) "34464"
    [13]=>
    string(5) "21778"
    [14]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [15]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [16]=>
    string(2) "93"
    [17]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [18]=>
    string(4) "1.28"
    [19]=>
    string(3) "8.0"
    [20]=>
    string(8) "15:04:16"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(21) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "49986826"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "292415"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [6]=>
    string(3) "622"
    [7]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [8]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [9]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [10]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [11]=>
    string(4) "1226"
    [12]=>
    string(5) "31334"
    [13]=>
    string(5) "20273"
    [14]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [15]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [16]=>
    string(2) "94"
    [17]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [18]=>
    string(4) "1.21"
    [19]=>
    string(3) "7.5"
    [20]=>
    string(8) "15:04:46"
  }
}
```

1. I need to append today's date to each of the 20th elements in each array (need to make it date and time)

   $now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
   $today=$now->format('Y-m-d');

I tried this:

```
foreach ($lines as $key => $value){
   $lines[$key][20]=$today . ' ' . $lines[$key][20];
   echo $lines[$key][20];

}
```

looks like it worked.

2 . I need to insert this into an oracle db. I was curious to see if there is already a method or function to insert each array within `lines` array into the table.

Comment: Your db is of what type?

Comment: @Daedalus, it is oracle

Comment: The same way it works with other databases. Connect to it and see if you can do simple inserts. When you can, then do an insert on your foreach and debug accordingly. I don't get what you are asking us here, read your own question and get in our shoes, what do you expect us to help you with?

Comment: I'm asking for specifics, not generalizations.

Comment: There isn't an easy way to import an array like this (that I know of). If you already had a table setup with that many columns you could loop over array, oci_parse a query and use [oci_bind_by_name](http://www.php.net/oci_bind_by_name) to bind an array. It would still be a little manual, but possible.

Comment: @DAny Caissy, I guess what I am asking is how do you serialize this associative array in php?

Comment: .. Why not just use `json_encode()` or `serialize()`?

Comment: @Daedalus, I really appreciate this. Let's assume I used something like this $data<-json_encode($lines), I get values like this: [["6","1","0","49989317","290887","1","454","0","0","0","0","854","21539","18134","2","1","97","0","0.61","3.8","2013-06-25 15:59:47"],["8","1","0","49989686","294428","3","505","0","0","0","0","942","94395","21331","2","2","96","0","0.80","5.0","2013-06-25 16:00:17"],["6","1","0","49991010","296034","7","505","0","0","0","0","1014","26823","18428","3","1","95","1","0.81","5.0","2013-06-25 16:00:47"]], How would I insert this to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to serialize an array for insertion into a database, one would either use [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), or [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php); I personally like `json_encode()`, as it is easier to read and modify.

Both of these functions convert an array or the like into an encoded string, which you can then either insert into a column for text-based data.

To do the actual action of insertion.. that actually depends upon the version of the db you are using, because the following code only works for 11g, 10g, 9i and 8i.

Note the following isn't exactly real code, and you will have to adapt it to suit your needs, following the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.oci8.php).

```
<?php

$str = json_encode($lines); //convert to string.  You should have properly escaped the data prior to this/ran it through some function to escape the data.  We don't want injection attacks to occur
$conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', 'localhost'); //connect to database

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, "insert into tablename ('column')
          values('$str')"); // construct statement
oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT); // statement executed/data inserted

?>
```

Comment: As an important aside, always make sure you properly escape your data before insertion, to prevent injection attacks.